# In my Case Statement it always return the else value

Tags: oracle11g

In my query i use a case statement which always return the else value , here the query:

```
CASE WHEN CC.IBUS_CODE = null then to_char(vDQ.COA_CAT_ID)  ELSE (vDQ.COA_CAT_ID ||' | '||CC.IBUS_CODE) end AS COA_CAT_ID

here is the output 
COA_CAT_ID
4800 | 
4700 | 31113
4600 | 31112
4500 | 31111
4900 | 


Expected output 
  COA_CAT_ID
    4800 
    4700 | 31113
    4600 | 31112
    4500 | 31111
    4900
```

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: If you're getting the `|` character when you seemingly shouldn't be, it must mean that your `CC.IBUS_CODE` isn't really null. If the field consists of just spaces, you could try `ltrim(cc.ibus_code)`.

Comment: CC.IBUS_CODE  field is null and i am 100% sure about it .
i think it's problem in Then condition but i am not sure about it .

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your case expression is that you are checking for a column equaling null - that isn't right. `= null` is something that would return null instead of true or false, meaning your case statement would always drop into the else section.

Instead, you need to use `is null`, e.g.:

```
CASE WHEN CC.IBUS_CODE is null
          then to_char(vDQ.COA_CAT_ID)
     ELSE (vDQ.COA_CAT_ID ||' | '||CC.IBUS_CODE)
END AS COA_CAT_ID
```

[Here's a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2cca262a916f98277550b4ed04181744) that demonstrates the issue and fix.